# Creating partitioned Hive table using existing CSV file

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to load CSV file as partitioned Hive Table using Spark SQL and Start a thrift server. Here is what I tried:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf
    conf
      .set("hive.server2.thrift.port", "10000")
      .set("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", "true")
      .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://sql/metadata/hive")
      .set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
      .set("skip.header.line.count","1")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("ThriftServer")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()    

    spark.sql(
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS freq (" +
        "time_stamp bigint," +
        "time_quality string )" +
        "PARTITIONED BY (id int) "
        "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED " +
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " +
        "STORED AS TEXTFILE " +
        "LOCATION 'Path_to_CSV_file' " +
        "TBLPROPERTIES(skip.header.line.count = 1)"
    )
```

Using the above code the freq table will be created and data is loaded on it but it's not partitioned based on the column *id*. I also tried Altering table or inserting data based on partition key but it was not successful.

Alter Table:

```scala
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE freq ADD PARTITION (id) " +
      "LOCATION 'PATH_TO_CSV_FILE' ")
ERROR: Found an empty partition key 'id'.(line 1, pos 33)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE freq ADD PARTITION (id) LOCATION 'Path_To_CSV_File'
```

Insert Table:

```scala
spark.sql(
      "INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE freq PARTITION (id) " +
      "SELECT * " +
      "FROM freq"
    )
ERROR: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: id is not a valid partition column in table `database`.`freq`.;
```

The first question is what is the correct way to create a partitioned table using SparkSQL and Hive?

In addition, as I have data in CSV file in advance, I don't want to create a copy of them (because of capacity limitation) and I want to have just one replica of that (no matter in form of CSV file or in the form of Hive Partitions subdirectories). Is it possible?

Comment: You need to specify the partition value as well, e.g. `ALTER TABLE freq ADD PARTITION (id = '1') LOCATION 'PATH_TO_CSV_FILE_DIRECTORY'`, plus you cannot create a partition for a single file, just for directories

Comment: Couldn't Hive detect the values for column `id` and create a subdirectory for each of them?

Comment: No, you need to specify the partition value when manually adding new partition. Otherwise use dynamic partitioning.

Comment: Using dynamic partitioning it creates a new version of data in subdirectories. Is it possible to keep just a version of data?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no.